# Find content of lost git stash

Tags: git, awk

I have a git stash that I dropped by accident yesterday, and now I want to recover it. The problem is, I'm can't find it anymore.

I tried to get a list of all dangling commits like this:

```
git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'
```

This gives me a long list of sha1's. But how can I grep the diff of the commits with their parents? I was thinking about using xargs, but I'm not sure how to use the output of the `awk` command within xargs (how to reference the `SHA1_OUTPUT`)

```
git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' | xargs git diff SHA1_OUTPUT^ SHA1_OUPUT
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try this : git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d\ -f3 | xargs git log --oneline. to find the sha-1 and then git diff <sha1OfyourStash> if you manage to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me once when I cleared my stash bag by accident. I was only caring about one stash which was too important to loose and I recovered it thanks to its files names.

Actually if you remember well the names of your files which you want to recover, you can run

```
  git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' | xargs git show
```

And then you'll see modified files and what was modified. By relying on the search feature (/) you can look for the files you remember and you'll see the modifications, if they match you can get the hash and get it back

```
git reset <stash_hash>^
```

And why not stash again :D

```
git stash save "Stash my lost stash..."
```